# Configure PyDev for a project programmatically

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I'm using PyDev for an Eclipse RCP. Is it possible to configure PyDev for a project programmatically? It doesn't seem to have an API through Eclipse extension points.

It seems I can create a .pydevproject from scratch and modify the Eclipse .project file in order to add the PyDev nature, but it seems an ugly hack.